# Windows XP boot hangs at Mup.sys

Tags: windows-xp, installation

I'm trying to install Windows XP SP3 Professional on a Thinkpad X20. It has no optical drive, so I'm installing on a T40p and then moving the drive to the X20. Windows installed fine on the T40p, but when I first tried booting the moved disk on the X20 it hung at AGP440.sys. With that disabled, I get as far as Mup.sys.

I seem to remember installing Windows on the X20 before using this manoeuvre and the T40p, although it was certainly with an older version of Windows XP. Even so, it seems that the install generated on the T40p is just too specific to boot on the X20. Does anyone have ideas as to how I may resolve this, without having to install again on an older laptop, more similar to the X20?

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com....

Comment: Are you sure it's actually hanging? Try leaving it for half an hour. If scandisk runs silently at boot, it can look like a hang.

Comment: belongs on... wait. that site isn't open yet.

Does the system have USB? I would suggest a USB CDROM. Moving drives around on Windows is asking for trouble.

Comment: doesn't exist just yet though

Comment: @moonshadow, yeah it stops and then automatically reboots. I should have made this clear in the question.

Comment: @friism: just to confirm - it does reboot repeatedly if left alone, right? - it doesn't boot normally following the reboot? Scandisk will automatically reboot if it made changes. Sorry to harp on, but I wasted tons of time banging my head against the wall with variations on these symptoms on a number of occasions.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest attacking from an alternate angle:

1. Installing from a USB CDROM Drive (if you have one available)
2. Installing from a USB Drive: http://www.vandomburg.net/installing-windows-xp-from-usb/

You can use BartPE to build the bootable USB Key Drive installer [fairly easy](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-22_11-5928902.html), I've used this method to install XP onto an eeePC.

Comment: I don't have a USB CDROM drive, unfortunately. 2) looks like an option, but it's fairly involved. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: I have used method #2 before (I actually found that exact same article) on a laptop of my manager.  and interestingly enough I am doing it ona new netbook for our HR VP today.  It seems like a lot of work but once you have the ramdisk setup its just another installation.

Comment: It is easy for me to say, and I don't know your situation, but USB CD Drives are < $20 on ebay, it is an invaluable tech tool since sometimes you encounter PCs with Bad or No CD drive. Highly recommended.